# Excel - How can I get the average of cells where the value in one column is X and the value in another column is Y?

Tags: excel, field, average, cell

I want to display the average of Time Approved from a set of data like the below.
However, I only want to display the average of the Time Approved where the Approval Type = Yellow Type **and** Approver = Cathy.

I am able to leverage AverageIf() to just get the average time approved for Cathy, if I wanted... but what if I want the average of Cathy when the Approval Type is Yellow Type?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `AVERAGEIFS` ...

`=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C13,A2:A13,"Yellow Type",B2:B13,"Cathy")`

[image]

Comment: @bri, can you please flag it as the answer then?  It helps others and rewards those for helping.  Thanks